# Explicit function for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

Is there any general explicit formula for Bernoulli numbers ? Something like:

$$f(x)=B_x$$

Where $B_x$ is the $x$-th Bernoulli number ?

Searching the internet I only found the so-called "generating formula" or recursive relations but can there be an explicit formula ? And if it can't exist why ?

Comment: There is no known explicit formula for the Bernoulli, Euler, Genocchi, Bell, etc numbers. There are lots of known formulas to generate the numbers in various ways.

Comment: How could this be ? Those numbers are so fundamental! :( @Leucippus

Comment: If there were one, we would not bother to call them Bernoulli numbers. For example, they declined to call the numbers 1,3,5,7,9,11,13, etc. the Circonflexe numbers.

Comment: @RenatoFaraone: prime numbers are pretty fundamental too, but....

Comment: You wish probably something else than $\;f(x)=-x\cdot \zeta(1-x)$...

Comment: Yes @RaymondManzoni I know this formula but it doesn't help much ^^

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783503/bernoulli-numbers-explicit-form

Comment: I found that the following eleven questions are closely-related or almost the same questions:
(1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783503/, 
(2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580748/, 
(3) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273516/, 
(4) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568817/, 
(5) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257544/, 
(6) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783503/,

Comment: (7) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447276/, 
(8) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504814/, 
(9) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739872/, 
(10) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451797/, 
(11) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107114/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit formula
\begin{equation}\label{Higgins-Gould-B}\tag{1}
B_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}j^n,\quad n\ge0,
\end{equation}
has a long history, it appeared in the paper

1. H. W. Gould, *Explicit formulas for Bernoulli numbers*, Amer. Math. Monthly **79** (1972), 44--51; available online at https://doi.org/10.2307/2978125.

It is a special case of the formula (2.5) in the paper

2. J. Higgins, *Double series for the Bernoulli and Euler numbers*, J. London Math. Soc. $2$nd Ser. **2** (1970), 722--726; Available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/2.Part_4.722.

Its equivalent form is
\begin{equation}\label{Bernoulli-Stirling-eq}\tag{2}
B_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{k!}{k+1}S(n,k), \quad n\ge0,
\end{equation}
where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling numbers of the second kind. See page 29, Remark 2 in the paper

3. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *An explicit formula for Bernoulli numbers in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind*, Journal of Analysis & Number Theory **3** (2015), no. 1, 27--30.

There existed at least seven alternative proofs of the formulas \eqref{Higgins-Gould-B} and \eqref{Bernoulli-Stirling-eq} in the paper [1, 2] above and in the following monographs and papers:

4. L. Comtet, *Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions*, Revised and Enlarged Edition, D. Reidel Publishing Co., Dordrecht and Boston, 1974, page 220.
5. R. L. Graham, D. E. Knuth, and O. Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics---A Foundation for Computer Science*, 2nd ed., Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, Reading, MA, 1994.
6. B.-N. Guo and F. Qi, *Alternative proofs of a formula for Bernoulli numbers in terms of Stirling numbers*, Analysis (Berlin) **34** (2014), no. 2, 187--193; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/anly-2012-1238.
7. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Alternative proofs of a formula for Bernoulli numbers in terms of Stirling numbers*, Analysis (Berlin) **34** (2014), no. 3, 311--317; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/anly-2014-0003.

To the best of my knowledge, except the formulas \eqref{Higgins-Gould-B} and \eqref{Bernoulli-Stirling-eq} above, there are also the following explicit formulas for the Bernoulli numbers $B_n$:
\begin{align}\label{Higgins-Gould-B(11)}\tag{3}
B_n&=\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom{n+1}{j+1}\frac{n!}{(n+j)!}\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^{j-k}\binom{j}{k}k^{n+j}, \quad n\ge0;\\
B_n&=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i}\frac{\binom{n+1}{i+1}}{\binom{n+i}{i}}S(n+i,i), \quad n\ge0;\label{Bernoulli-Stirling-formula}\tag{4}\\
B_{2k}&=1+\sum_{m=1}^{2k-1}\frac{S(2k+1,m+1) S(2k,2k-m)}{\binom{2k}{m}}\\
&\quad-\frac{2k}{2k+1}\sum_{m=1}^{2k}\frac{S(2k,m)S(2k+1,2k-m+1)}{\binom{2k}{m-1}}, \quad k\in\mathbb{N};\tag{5}\\
B_{2k}&=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{2^{2(k-1)}(2^{2k}-1)}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-i-1} (-1)^{i+\ell}\binom{2k}{\ell}(k-i-\ell)^{2k-1}, \quad k\in\mathbb{N};\tag{6}\\
B_{2m}&=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{m} {2^{2m-1}\bigl(2^{2m}-1\bigr)}\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k\binom{2m}{k}(m-k)^{2m-1}\\
&\quad+2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(-1)^k\sum_{\ell=0}^{m-k-1} (-1)^{\ell}\binom{2m}{\ell}(m-k-\ell)^{2m-1}\Biggr],\quad m\in\mathbb{N};\\
B_{2m}&=\frac{m} {2^{2m-1}\bigl(2^{2m}-1\bigr)}\sum_{\ell=1}^{2m}\frac{(-1)^{\ell-1}}{2^\ell} \biggl(\frac1\ell-\frac1{m+1}\biggr) \binom{2m+1}{\ell} \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^{2m}, \quad m\in\mathbb{N};\\
B_{2k}&= \frac12 - \frac1{2k+1} - 2k \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}
\frac{A_{2(k-i)}}{2(k - i) + 1},\quad k\in\mathbb{N};\tag{7}
\end{align}
where $A_m$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{m=1}^nm^k=\sum_{m=0}^{k+1}A_mn^{m}.
\end{equation*}
The formulas \eqref{Higgins-Gould-B(11)} and \eqref{Bernoulli-Stirling-formula} are also equivalent to eah other.

By the way, I would like to mention two intereting double inequalities related to the Bernoulli numbers $B_{2n}$ as follows.

- The double inequality
  \begin{equation}\label{Bernoulli-ineq}\tag{8}
  \frac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}} \frac{1}{1-2^{\alpha -2n}} \le |B_{2n}| \le \frac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}\frac{1}{1-2^{\beta -2n}}
  \end{equation}
  is valid for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\alpha=0$ and
  $
  \beta=2+\frac{\ln(1-6/\pi^2)}{\ln2}=0.6491\dotsc
  $
  are the best possible in the sense that they can not be replaced respectively by any bigger and smaller constants in the double inequality \eqref{Bernoulli-ineq}. See the paper [8] below.
- The ratios $\frac{|B_{2(n+1)}|}{|B_{2n}|}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be bounded by
  \begin{equation}\label{ineq-Bernou-equiv}\tag{9}
  \frac{2^{2n-1}-1}{2^{2n+1}-1}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{\pi^2}
  <\frac{|B_{2(n+1)}|}{|B_{2n}|}
  <\frac{2^{2n}-1}{2^{2n+2}-1}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{\pi^2}.
  \end{equation}
  See the paper [9] below.

More related references

8. H. Alzer, *Sharp bounds for the Bernoulli numbers*, Arch. Math. (Basel) **74** (2000), no. 3, 207--211; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s000130050432.
9. Feng Qi, *A double inequality for the ratio of two non-zero neighbouring Bernoulli numbers*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **351** (2019), 1--5; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2018.10.049.
10. Sumit Kumar Jha, *Two new explicit formulas for the Bernoulli numbers*, Integers **20** (2020), Paper No. A21, 5 pp.
11. Sumit Kumar Jha, *Two new explicit formulas for the even-indexed Bernoulli numbers*, J. Integer Seq. **23** (2020), no. 2, Art. 20.2.6, 6 pp.
12. Sumit Kumar Jha, *A new explicit formula for Bernoulli numbers involving the Euler number*, Mosc. J. Comb. Number Theory **8** (2019), no. 4, 385--387; availble online at https://doi.org/10.2140/moscow.2019.8.389.
13. B.-N. Guo and F. Qi, *Some identities and an explicit formula for Bernoulli and Stirling numbers*, J. Comput. Appl. Math. **255** (2014), 568--579; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.06.020.
14. S.-L. Guo and F. Qi, *Recursion formulae for $\sum_{m=1}^nm^k$*, Z. Anal. Anwendungen **18** (1999), no. 4, 1123--1130; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/ZAA/933.
15. S. Jeong, M.-S. Kim, and J.-W. Son, *On explicit formulae for Bernoulli numbers and their counterparts in positive characteristic*, J. Number Theory **113** (2005), no. 1, 53; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2004.08.013.
16. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Applied Mathematics and Computation **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
17. L. Saalschutz, *Vorlesungen uber die Bernoulli'schen Zahlen, ihren Zusammenhang mit den Secanten-Coefficienten und ihre wichtigeren Anwendungen*, Berlin, 1893. Available since 1964 in Xerographed form from University Microfilms, Ann Arbor, Michigan. Order No. OP-17136.
18. S. Shirai and K.-I. Sato, *Some identities involving Bernoulli and Stirling numbers*, J. Number Theory **90** (2001), no. 1, 130--142; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jnth.2001.2659.
19. Chao-Ping Chen and Feng Qi, *Three improper integrals relating to the generating function of Bernoulli numbers*, Octogon Mathematical Magazine **11**(2003), no. 2, 408--409.
20. Ye Shuang, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Logarithmic convexity and increasing property of the Bernoulli numbers and their ratios*, Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas Fisicas y Naturales Serie A Matematicas **115** (2021), no. 3, Paper No. 135, 12 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s13398-021-01071-x.
21. Feng Qi, *Notes on a double inequality for ratios of any two neighbouring non-zero Bernoulli numbers*, Turkish Journal of Analysis and Number Theory **6** (2018), no. 5, 129--131; available online at https://doi.org/10.12691/tjant-6-5-1.
22. Z.-H. Yang and J.-F. Tian, *Sharp bounds for the ratio of two zeta functions*, J. Comput. Appl. Math. **364** (2020), 112359, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2019.112359.
23. L. Zhu, *New bounds for the ratio of two adjacent even-indexed Bernoulli numbers*, Rev. R. Acad. Cienc. Exactas Fis. Nat. Ser. A Mat. RACSAM **114** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 83, 13 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s13398-020-00814-6.

Comment: Thanks for the References. Amazing answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, something like the explicite formula for $e^x$ perhaps, an infinite series...?

This is possible (as in the comment of Raymond Manzoni), however, the infinite series is divergent (but alternating, so Cesaro or Eulersummable).

Here is such an explicite formula:

$$B_{x+1} = f(x) = \left(1^x -2^x +3^x-4^x + ... - ...\right) \cdot{ 1+x\over 1-2 \cdot 2^x} $$

Comment: The correct answer to this question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254493/945479.

Answer (score 2):

In the paper [2], the Bernoulli polynomials $B_n(x)$ were determinantally expressed as
\begin{equation}
B_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & \dotsm & x^{n-1} & x^n\\
1 & \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac14 & \dotsm & \frac1n & \frac1{n+1}\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dotsm & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & \dotsm & n-1 & n\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \binom32 & \dotsm & \binom{n-1}2 & \binom{n}2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & \binom{n-1}{n-2} & \binom{n}{n-2}
\end{vmatrix}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}
In the paper [1] below, the Bernoulli polynomials $B_n(x)$ were represented as
\begin{align*}
B_n(x)&=(-1)^nn!
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
\frac{x}{1!} & \frac1{2!} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
\frac{x^2}{2!} & \frac1{3!} & \frac1{2!} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
\frac{x^3}{3!} & \frac1{4!} & \frac1{3!} & \frac1{2!} & 1 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm\\
\frac{x^n}{n!} & \frac1{(n+1)!} & \frac1{n!} & \frac1{(n-1)!} & \frac1{(n-2)!}&\frac1{(n-3)!}&\dotsm& 1
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{\prod_{k=1}^nk!}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
x & \frac1{2!} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
x^2 & \frac{2!}{3!} & 1 & 2! & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
x^3 & \frac{3!}{4!} & 1 & \frac{3!}{2!} & 3! & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm\\
x^n & \frac{n!}{(n+1)!} & 1 & \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} & \frac{n!}{(n-2)!}&\frac{n!}{(n-3)!}&\dotsm& n!
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(-1)^n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(k-1)!}{k!}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
x & \frac1{2!} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
x^2 & \frac{2!}{3!} & 1 & 2! & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
x^3 & \frac{3!}{4!} & 1 & \frac{3!}{2!} & \frac{3!}{2!} & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm\\
x^n & \frac{n!}{(n+1)!} & 1 & \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} & \frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}&\frac{n!}{(n-3)!3!}&\dotsm& \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align*}
In the paper [4], the Bernoulli polynomials $B_n(x)$ was explicitly expressed as
\begin{multline}\label{BP-Stirl-form}
B_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nk!\sum_{r+s=k}\sum_{\ell+m=n}(-1)^m\binom{n}{\ell} \frac{\ell!}{(\ell+r)!}\frac{m!}{(m+s)!}\\
\times\Biggl[\sum_{i=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^s(-1)^{i+j}\binom{\ell+r}{r-i}\binom{m+s}{s-j}S(\ell+i,i)S(m+j,j)\Biggr]x^{m+s}(1-x)^{\ell+r}
\end{multline}
and was determinantally represented as
\begin{equation}\label{Bern-Polyn-determ}
B_n(x)=(-1)^n\biggl|\frac1{\ell+1}\binom{\ell+1}{m} \bigl[(1-x)^{\ell-m+1}-(-x)^{\ell-m+1}\bigr]\biggr|_{1\le \ell\le n,0\le m\le n-1}
\end{equation}
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $S(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind and $|\cdot|_{1\le \ell\le n,0\le m\le n-1}$ denotes a $n\times n$ determinant.

In the paper [5], an alternative determinantal expression
\begin{equation}\label{Bernoulli-Polyn-Det-Erew}
B_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&0&0&\dotsm&0&0&0\\
\frac{x}2&\binom{2}0&\frac12&0&\dotsm&0&0&0\\
\frac{x^2}3&\binom{3}0&\binom{3}1&\frac13&\dotsm&0&0&0\\
\frac{x^3}4&\binom{4}0&\binom{4}1&\binom{4}2&\dotsm&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\frac{x^{n-2}}{n-1}&\binom{n-1}0&\binom{n-1}1&\binom{n-1}2&\dotsm &\binom{n-1}{n-3}&\frac1{n-1}&0\\
\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}&\binom{n}0&\binom{n}1&\binom{n}2&\dotsm &\binom{n}{n-3}&\binom{n}{n-2}&\frac1{n}\\
\frac{x^n}{n+1}&\binom{n+1}0&\binom{n+1}1&\binom{n+1}2&\dotsm &\binom{n+1}{n-3}&\binom{n+1}{n-2}&\binom{n+1}{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}, \quad n\ge0
\end{equation}
for the Bernoulli numbers $B_n(x)$ was derived.

Theorem 1.1 in [3] reads that, for all integers $n,r\ge0$, the Bernoulli polynomials $B_n(r)$ can be computed in terms of the $r$-Stirling numbers of the second kind $S_r(n,k)$ by
\begin{equation}\label{Bernoulli-Poly-r-Stirling-eq}
B_n(r)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{k!}{k+1}S_r(n,k).
\end{equation}

**When taking $x=0$ in the above determinatal expressions and closed-form expressions, we can arrive at closed-form formulas for the Bernoulli numbers $B_n=B_n(0)$.**

References

1. R. Booth and H. D. Nguyen, *Bernoulli polynomials and Pascal's square*, Fibonacci Quart. **46/47** (2008/2009), no. 1, 38--47.
2. F. Costabile, F. Dell'Accio, M. I. Gualtieri, *A new approach to Bernoulli polynomials*, Rend. Mat. Appl. (7) **26** (2006), no. 1, 1--12.
3. B.-N. Guo, I. Mezo, and F. Qi, *An explicit formula for the Bernoulli polynomials in terms of the $r$-Stirling numbers of the second kind*, Rocky Mountain J. Math. **46** (2016), no. 6, 1919--1923; available online at https://doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-2016-46-6-1919.
4. F. Qi and R. J. Chapman, *Two closed forms for the Bernoulli polynomials*, J. Number Theory **159** (2016), 89--100; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2015.07.021.
5. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Some determinantal expressions and recurrence relations of the Bernoulli polynomials*, Mathematics **4** (2016), no. 4, Article 65, 11 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/math4040065.