# Asymptotic Expansion of Digamma Function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, digamma-function

While reading the wikipedia page of the Digamma function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Asymptotic_expansion)

I noticed that it said the asymptotic expansion for the digamma function ($\psi(z)$) can be obtained from using

\begin{equation} \psi(z+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+z}) \end{equation} (where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant) combined with Euler–Maclaurin formula to conclude

\begin{equation} \psi(z) \approx \log(z) - \frac{1}{2z} \end{equation}   My main confusion about this is that when I tried to use the Euler–Maclaurin formula to approximate the sum as an integral, I could not figure out how to obtain a $\gamma$ to cancel out the $\gamma$ term in the series expansion. Any  help on how to obtain the above relationship using the formula or just where the $\gamma$ comes from when I apply the Euler-Maclaurian formula would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall assume that $|\arg (z+1)|<\pi$. By the Euler–Maclaurin formula,
\begin{align*}
\psi (z + 1) = &  - \gamma  + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{{t + z}}} \right)dt}  + \frac{1}{2}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{1 + z}}} \right) \\ & + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\left( {\left\{ {1 - t} \right\} - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{{t^2 }} - \frac{1}{{(t + z)^2 }}} \right)dt} 
\\  = & \; \log (z + 1) - \gamma  + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ {1 - t} \right\}}}{{t^2 }}dt}  - \frac{1}{{2(z + 1)}} - \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ {1 - t} \right\} - \frac{1}{2}}}{{(t + z)^2 }}dt}.
\end{align*}
Thus, it remains to show that
$$
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ {1 - t} \right\}}}{{t^2 }}dt}  = \gamma 
$$
and
$$
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ {1 - t} \right\} - \frac{1}{2}}}{{(t + z)^2 }}dt}  = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{(z + 1)^2 }}} \right).
$$
The first one can be shown as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ {1 - t} \right\}}}{{t^2 }}dt} & =\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\int_k^{k + 1} {\frac{{\left\{ {1 - t} \right\}}}{{t^2 }}dt} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\int_0^1 {\frac{{1 - t}}{{(k + t)^2 }}dt} } \\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left[ {\frac{1}{k} - \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)} \right]}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left[ {\frac{1}{k} - \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)} \right]} 
\\ &
 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left(\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  - \log (n + 1) \right)= \gamma .
\end{align*}
For the second claim, we use integration by parts and some estimations to obtain
\begin{align*}
& \left| {\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ {1 - t} \right\} - \frac{1}{2}}}{{(t + z)^2 }}dt} } \right| = \left| {\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ t \right\} - \left\{ t \right\}^2 }}{{(t + z)^3 }}dt} } \right| \\ & \le \frac{1}{4}\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\left| {t + z} \right|^3 }}dt}  = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\left| {t + (z + 1)} \right|^3 }}dt} 
\\ &
 \le \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{(t + \left| {z + 1} \right|)^3 }}dt} \sec ^3 \left( {\frac{{\arg (z + 1)}}{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{{8\left| {z + 1} \right|^2 }}\sec ^3 \left( {\frac{{\arg (z + 1)}}{2}} \right).
\end{align*}
In summary, replacing $z+1$ by $z$,
$$
\psi (z) = \log z - \frac{1}{{2z}} + R(z)
$$
where
$$
\left| {R(z)} \right| \le \frac{1}{{8\left| z \right|^2 }}\sec ^3 \left( {\frac{{\arg z}}{2}} \right)
$$
and $|\arg z|<\pi$. With more careful considerations, the constant $\frac{1}{8}$ can be replaced by $\frac{1}{12}$.

Answer (score 3):

The harmonic number $H_{n}$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
H_n=1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{equation*}
and satisfies
\begin{equation*}%\label{def-gamma}
\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_n-\ln n)=0.57721\dotsc
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}\label{H-gamma}
H_n=\psi(n+1)+\gamma,
\end{equation*}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler–-Mascheroni constant and $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function which is the logarithmic derivative of the classical Euler gamma function
\begin{equation*}%\label{gamma-dfn}
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}\textrm{e}^{-t}\textrm{d}\,t, \quad \Re(z)>0.
\end{equation*}

Is the Euler–-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ irrational? This is a famous but unsolved problem. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html.

On page 257 and page 260 in the handbook [1] below, the formulas 6.1.40 and 6.4.11 read that
\begin{align}\label{ln-gamma-symp-eq}
\ln\Gamma(w)&\sim\biggl(w-\frac12\biggr)\ln w-w+\frac12\ln(2\pi)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{2k(2k-1)w^{2k-1}},\\
\psi(w)&\sim\ln w-\frac{1}{2w}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{2kw^{2k}},\label{ln-psi-symp-eq}
\end{align}
and
\begin{equation}\label{asymptotic-polypsi}
\psi^{(n)}(w)\sim(-1)^{n-1}\biggl[\frac{(n-1)!}{w^n}+\frac{n!}{2w^{n+1}}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty B_{2k}\frac{(2k+n-1)!}{(2k)!w^{2k+n}}\biggr]
\end{equation}
as $w\to\infty$ in $\lvert \arg w\rvert<\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $B_{2k}$ for $k\ge1$ are known as the Bernoulli numbers which can be generated by
\begin{equation*}%\label{Bernoulli-numbers-dfn}
\frac{w}{e^w-1}=1-\frac{w}2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty B_{2k}\frac{w^{2k}}{(2k)!}, \quad| w| <2\pi.
\end{equation*}
See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254493/945479, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4256893/945479, and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4248341/945479.

References

1. M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun (Eds), *Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables*, National Bureau of Standards, Applied Mathematics Series **55**, Reprint of the 1972 edition, Dover Publications, Inc., New York, 1992.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Sharp inequalities for the psi function and harmonic numbers*, Analysis---International mathematical journal of analysis and its applications **34** (2014), no. 2, 201--208; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/anly-2014-0001.
3. Da-Wei Niu, Yue-Jin Zhang, and Feng Qi, *A double inequality for the harmonic number in terms of the hyperbolic cosine*, Turkish Journal of Analysis and Number Theory **2** (2014), no. 6, 223--225; available online at https://doi.org/10.12691/tjant-2-6-6.
4. N. M. Temme, *Special Functions: An Introduction to Classical Functions of Mathematical Physics*, A Wiley-Interscience Publication, John Wiley & Sons, Inc., New York, 1996; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9781118032572.