# Bernoulli numbers and $\tan(x)$ expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am looking up on the Bernoulli numbers and their connection to $\tan(x)$ power series and I see this thread:

[Bernoulli numbers, taylor series expansion of tan x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098941/bernoulli-numbers-taylor-series-expansion-of-tan-x)

In it, Rob John manipulate the series of

[image]

The part I don't understand is circled in red. What is the general formula for $-2\cot(2x)$? How do you combine the formula to produce the last one for $\tan(x)$. I don't understand that part of his manipulation. Can you do it in a few more steps so I can learn?

Comment: this is just taking the two series for $cot(x)$ and $2cot(2x)$ and subtracting them, putting them inside the same series

Comment: @George Dewhirst: But what is the sigma notation formula for $\2cot(2x)$. Of course I can manually do that with expanded form, but I wish to know how to manipulate it using the sigma notation formula.

Comment: just replace $x$ by $2x$ in the formula and take $2^{2n-1}
$ out as a factor

Comment: What about the subtracting part? How do you derive it, I mean the second red circle part.

Comment: the sum operator is linear

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst: Sorry I don't know what is a linear operator. I am still a noob haha!

Comment: haha ok basically it is fine to do this: $\sum a_n + \sum b_n = \sum (a_n + b_n)$ and likewise if it a subtraction

Comment: @George Dewhirst I just don't know the second red circled part.

Comment: basically the $B_{2n}2^{2n}$ is common to both series, and the first term in the brackets is from $cot(x)$, the second is from $cot(2x)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101397/discussion-between-james-warthington-and-george-dewhirst).

Comment: Basically, the part I don't understand is $x^{2n-1}-2 \cdot2^{2n-1}x^{2n-1}$

Comment: That's just $x^{2n-1}-2(2x)^{2n-1}$, which is what you get when you do the things everyone has told you in the comments so far.

Comment: $cot(x) - 2cot(2x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n  B_{2n} 2^{2n} x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} - 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n  B_{2n} 2^{2n} 2^{2n-1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n  B_{2n} (x^{2n-1} - 2*2^{2n-1} x^{2n-1})}{(2n)!}$

Comment: Ok, I see thank you! :)

Comment: One answer to this question can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254671/945479.

Comment: I found that the following eleven questions are closely-related or almost the same questions:
(1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783503/, 
(2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580748/, 
(3) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273516/, 
(4) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568817/, 
(5) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257544/, 
(6) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783503/,

Comment: (7) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447276/, 
(8) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504814/, 
(9) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739872/, 
(10) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451797/, 
(11) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107114/.